# Why is TypeScript not giving an error when pushing object with missing property to array?

Tags: typescript

Given these type definitions:

```
type ChildA = { a: number }
type ChildB = ChildA & { b: number }

type ParentA = { children: ChildA[] }
type ParentB = ParentA & { children: ChildB[] }
```

This causes a TypeScript error, as expected:

```
const parentB1: ParentB = { children: [{ a: 1 }] }

// Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ChildA & { b: number; }'.
//   Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.
```

This also causes a TypeScript error, as expected:

```
const children: ChildB[] = []
children.push({ a: 1 })

// Argument of type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChildB'.
//  Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.
```

However, this does not cause a TypeScript error.

```
const parentB2: ParentB = { children: [] }
parentB2.children.push({ a: 1 }) // no error
```

Why is there no error? I see that `parentB2.children` is of type `ChildA[] & ChildB[]`. So why is TypeScript not showing the same error as the previous examples?

Here's the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4ejYHEEsDcCmA7YAXAFggzgtBPAB1wBMEAzGJGVGAeySwChR8jgBhdGAG2IEFgAXmABvYAEMAXMCQBXALYAjBACdgAX2ahUhXJx7EAQkI5deAgGSjgi6XKWqNjLSB1sACuJXJUA4WIBjM2JvJGl9cwBtAF0nFjdcT1DUY2Ekn0trIINQ8ODDGKdnFghgABUuLGAA8VkcKvFy3QBlAJUYAlRgVRVaFQAaCSqEAA8iANQEYhdQUrLdYAByMSkZBWUVAG4NReAYKqRaLvEsLBgAcyRxRW5cVFpWXEWI-mArMVs1hy2dgDoZkClEDuXpEFQ6JaKXb7YDyfZnJDnPYoBJLFZ2daqbbqXaKWRdbwAR1kMG8xGRjzRNgx32xi3%20LAC9CwXQIXh8hgAjNJ0kgUiZAsFcsBIujgJyNLFNDM5pUJNwsA8anVsBImkRWu1Ot0VL0BkNumMEBMpgDwJA%20CpzgofMBaGRKcsJDSNnS9gcjkMzpdrrc0A82SpxPIEJM1PbHS9DPSzUCQbQwRDFlD3bD4ZQkZRHWL7K6djZ8cAiSSyRTUU7PrmsX8ZkyGF1srxhVHCsIYrWhchfgQ6ugABRiiXqACUxVmkAAErQAO4IRD6jAw4i0VWHBu1HBq%20YatodLo9Pq-YAAdXQeAA-LHIABJYA4O7ocSs9l8wwAJl%20jZCyFTEdRLz4QorBbaIr2AZoHmnM9U23BBNT3GRPSwdAZwzNBMDvYNcAPNQTnQ3ACG8OA6DqQ1gwIW4sEvRlmWfZJ3x5F9%20X8apOzCEUpRmQMOQ-L9Qm7XsB2dcUNGHIA) for this example.

---

Edit: Thank you to jcalz for providing the comment with the root cause being from intersection of arrays. To work around this TypeScript behavior and provide the errors as expected, I simplify modified `type ParentB` to omit the `children` property from `ParentA` type:

```
type ParentB = Omit<ParentA, "children"> & { children: ChildB[] }
```

Here's the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEEsDcFMDtQBcAWsDOtkE8AOWATWAM0nkiUgHt50AoJPLAYRUgBsCBBUAXlADeoAIYAuUPACuAWwBGsAE6gAvgyahWHAgCE+Gtpx4AyQaFnipcxSrpr8oAArCFCJD35CAxgYIv44zUMAbQBdG0Z7Jz8kXX4AeWkKAB4o1y4AGlAAIm8tPyyAPlATLx8-AJ9tUJtbEFAAFTZ0UE9hSUxm4QamAGVPBUhcJFBFBSoFTOFm2AAPfE8kWAI6UFA6+vUAciExCRl5BQBuFU3QSGb4KmGp9EgAc3hhWXYsJCoce03A7mLTcz2rEcTgA6FZrMCrBxjfAKRigTayU7nUCJdC3eB3M6ICJYbYiCz7RTHZSnWSSYYuACOkkgLgIWI+uKE-0sB2Jm1Bnho6GGuGcrm0AEZxKl4DE9KU8ghxEEduJBSowqo6OsmiJ2Oh3q12hgRN18H0BkMRgoxhMRNM5rAFkswXUuAo7jJXKAqMRGfC5QC2Sczhcrhbbg8ni9kO8+QphNJYIslG6PV9Khy7RCoVQYXCEUjmqj0ZiyAmvayib6yRTYNTaUsGTjPWYCYD2ZzucNcpxyvotFUwvxQnQ274EMDcO0UAAKL0K5QASlqYG02FA7TImISyVFbkyOTKCEKDI3ulrkdQ1lQwkQACt2sMNxkJFQAO6gTCvNAjK02+kbA39QbDUbjCmoAOk60Ziq67q1niuzFkCJJ+ve1xovcjzPK84bOFGMbWPGUHfNoyarHUjjQoomaIghuYrjWWxFoScGkuSoBUjSdI0Z8zINj6JLNrQvL8mK2gAEwigJ4oeC0O7+KA1SqBGApCcCA5+MOo4TvioBTtOQA) for this showing all 3 examples now having the expected error.

Comment: Intersections of arrays behave strangely. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874 and the answer to the linked question.